# Autocomplete en modal no trabaja

Tags: javascript

Tengo una aplicacion hecha en asp net mvc e hice un popup modal para registrar productos, tengo un autocomplete en dicho modal pero los resultados aparecen atras del modal, adjunto imagen

[image: Agregar producto en ventana modal]

en mi controller hago la llamada al servicio y el servicio consulta la base de datos y todo va bien, el controlador recibe la letra que el usuario ingresa, el controlador llama al servicio WCF que va a la base de datos y me regresa una lista fuertemente tipada con la información que necesito dependiendo de la letra ingresada.

pues no entiendo que hago mal, podrian ayudarme, este es mi codigo

View:

```js
@section scripts{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function Agregar() {
            $('#linkAdd').attr('href', function () {
                return this.href.replace('__prdid__', $('#Bodega').val());
            });
        };

        $("#buscarcliente").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("BuscarPersonas", "Mov_Enc_D_Facts")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: { search: $("#buscarcliente").val() },
            success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name, id: item.Id, dias: item.Dias };
            }));
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
            }
            });
    },

    select: function (event, ui) {
    $('#idcliente').val(ui.item.id);
    $('#diascredito').val(ui.item.dias);
    }
    });

    function selectBox_valueChanged(data) {
    var rfecha1 = document.getElementById("fechatxt").value;

    $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("registro_Numeracion", "Mov_Enc_D_Facts")',
    dataType: "text",
    data: { id: data.value.id, fecha: rfecha1 },
    success: function (data1) {
    var inputNombre = document.getElementById("factura");
    inputNombre.value = data1;
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    alert(error);
    }
    });
    }

    function ContadoOnChange(element) {
        document.getElementById("Credito").disabled = element.checked;
    }

        function ImpuestoOnChange(element) {
            document.getElementById("chkimpuesto").value = element.checked;
        }

        function CreditoOnChange(element) {
        document.getElementById("Contado").disabled = element.checked;
        document.getElementById("diascredito").disabled = !element.checked;
    }
    </script>
}
```

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <br />

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" style="font-weight:bold">Nueva Factura</div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6, col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                <label for="buscarcliente">Cliente </label>
                                <input type="text" id="buscarcliente" name="buscarcliente" class="form-control" style="width: 100%" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-4, col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                <label>Fecha:</label>
                                <input class=" form-control" type="date" value="" id="fechatxt" name="fechatxt" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-2, col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                                <input class=" form-control" type="text" value="" id="idcliente" name="idcliente" hidden />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-4, col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                <label>Numeracion:</label>
                                @(Html.DevExtreme().SelectBox()
                                                                           .DisplayExpr("Descripcion")
                                                                           .DataSource(d => d.Mvc().Controller("Tipo_Numeracion_Usuarios").LoadAction("Numeracion_Usuario").Key("id"))
                                                                           .Value(1)
                                                                           .OnValueChanged("selectBox_valueChanged")
                                )
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4, col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                <label>Factura:</label>
                                <input class=" form-control" type="text" value="" id="factura" name="factura" disabled />
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-4, col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                <label>Vendedor</label>
                                @Html.DropDownList("Vendedor", listaVendedor, null, new { @class = "form-control ", style = "width: 100%;max-width: 100%;" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-4, col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                <label>Bodega</label>
                                @Html.DropDownList("Bodega", listaBodega, null, new { @class = "form-control ", style = "width: 100%;max-width: 100%;" })
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-4, col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                <label>Caja</label>
                                @Html.DropDownList("Caja", listaCaja, null, new { @class = "form-control ", style = "width: 100%;max-width: 100%;" })
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-2, col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                                <label>Dias Credito</label>
                                <input class=" form-control" type="text" value="" id="diascredito" name="diascredito" disabled />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-2, col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                                <label>Contado</label>
                                @Html.CheckBox("Contado", true, new { onchange = "ContadoOnChange(this)" })
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-2, col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                                <label>Credito</label>
                                @Html.CheckBox("Credito", false, new { onchange = "CreditoOnChange(this)", disabled = "true" })
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-4, col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                <label>Paga Impuesto</label>
                                @Html.CheckBox("Impuesto", true, new { onchange = "ImpuestoOnChange(this)" })
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-4, col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                @Ajax.ActionLink("Siguiente", "AgregarProducto", new {bodega = "__prdid__" }, new AjaxOptions()
                           {
                               HttpMethod = "GET",
                               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                               UpdateTargetId = "resultado",
                           }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", id = "linkAdd", onclick = "Agregar();" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-2, col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                                <input class=" form-control" type="text" value="true" id="chkimpuesto" name="chkimpuesto" hidden />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />

                <div id="resultado">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

PartialView

```js
<script>
    var impuesto;
    var bodega;
    var unidad
    var num = 0;
    var subtotal = 0;
    var timpuesto = 0;
    var total = 0;
    var tdescuento = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table').DataTable({
            "lengthChange": false,
            "order": [[1, "asc"]],
            "pageLength": 10
        });

        impuesto = $("#chkimpuesto").val();
        bodega = $("#Bodega").val();

        $("#btnShowModal").click(function () {
            $("#productoModal").modal('show');
        });

        $("#btnHideModal").click(function () {
            $("#productoModal").modal('hide');
        });  
    });

        $(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
            $("#Unidad").on("change", function () {
                $("#unidad").val($("#Unidad option:selected").text());
            });

            $("#buscarproducto").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("BuscarProductos", "Mov_Enc_D_Facts")',
            dataType: "json",
        data: { search: $("#buscarproducto").val() },
        success: function (data) {
        response($.map(data, function (item) {
        return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name, id: item.Id, precio: item.Price, impuesto: item.Impto };
        }));
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);
        }
        });
        },

        select: function (event, ui) {
        $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("buscar_existencia", "Mov_Enc_D_Facts")',
        dataType: "text",
            data: { producto: ui.item.id, bodega: bodega},
        success: function (data2) {
        var inputNombre = document.getElementById("existencia");
        inputNombre.value = data2;
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);
        }
        });
            $('#idproducto').val(ui.item.id);
            $('#precio').val(ui.item.precio);

            if (impuesto == "true") {
                $('#impuesto').val(ui.item.impuesto);
            } else {
                $('#impuesto').val(0);
            }
        }
            });
     });

        function AgregaConcepto() {
            let Codigo = document.getElementById("idproducto").value;
            let Descripcion = document.getElementById("buscarproducto").value;
            let Unidad = document.getElementById("unidad").value;
            let Cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
            let Precio = document.getElementById("precio").value;
            let Descuento = document.getElementById("descuento").value;
            let Impuesto = document.getElementById("impuesto").value;

            //agregamos tabla
            let Tabla = document.getElementById("table");
            let TBODY = document.createElement("tbody");
            let TR = document.createElement("tr");
            let TDCodigo = document.createElement("td");
            let TDDescripcion = document.createElement("td");
            let TDUnidad = document.createElement("td");
            let TDCantidad = document.createElement("td");
            let TDPrecio = document.createElement("td");
            let TDDescuento = document.createElement("td");
            let TDImpuesto = document.createElement("td");
            let TDTotal = document.createElement("td");

            TBODY.append(TR);

            TR.appendChild(TDCodigo);
            TR.appendChild(TDDescripcion);
            TR.appendChild(TDUnidad);
            TR.appendChild(TDCantidad);
            TR.appendChild(TDPrecio);
            TR.appendChild(TDDescuento);
            TR.appendChild(TDImpuesto);
            TR.appendChild(TDTotal);

            TDCodigo.innerHTML = Codigo;
            TDDescripcion.innerHTML = Descripcion;
            TDUnidad.innerHTML = Unidad;
            TDCantidad.innerHTML = Cantidad;
            TDPrecio.innerHTML = Precio;
            TDDescuento.innerHTML = ((parseFloat(Cantidad) * parseFloat(Precio)) * (parseFloat(Descuento) / 100)).toFixed(2);
            TDImpuesto.innerHTML = (((parseFloat(Cantidad) * parseFloat(Precio)) - ((parseFloat(Cantidad) * parseFloat(Precio)) * (parseFloat(Descuento) / 100))) * (parseFloat(Impuesto) / 100)).toFixed(2);
            TDTotal.innerHTML = (((parseFloat(Cantidad) * parseFloat(Precio)) - ((parseFloat(Cantidad) * parseFloat(Precio)) * (parseFloat(Descuento) / 100))) + (((parseFloat(Cantidad) * parseFloat(Precio)) - ((parseFloat(Cantidad) * parseFloat(Precio)) * (parseFloat(Descuento) / 100))) * (parseFloat(Impuesto) / 100))).toFixed(2);
            Tabla.appendChild(TBODY);

            //agregamos hiddens
            let DivConceptos = document.getElementById("divConceptos");
            let HiddenIndex = document.createElement("input");
            let HiddenCantidad = document.createElement("input");
            let HiddenDescripcion = document.createElement("input");
            let HiddenPrecio = document.createElement("input");

            HiddenIndex.name = "conceptos.Index";
            HiddenIndex.value = num;
            HiddenIndex.type = "hidden";
            HiddenCantidad.name = "conceptos[" + num + "].Cantidad";
            HiddenCantidad.value = Cantidad;
            HiddenCantidad.type = "hidden";
            HiddenDescripcion.name = "conceptos[" + num + "].Descripcion";
            HiddenDescripcion.value = Descripcion;
            HiddenDescripcion.type = "hidden";
            HiddenPrecio.name = "conceptos[" + num + "].PrecioUnitario";
            HiddenPrecio.value = Precio;
            HiddenPrecio.type = "hidden";
            DivConceptos.appendChild(HiddenIndex);
            DivConceptos.appendChild(HiddenCantidad);
            DivConceptos.appendChild(HiddenDescripcion);
            DivConceptos.appendChild(HiddenPrecio);

            num++;
            subtotal += ((parseFloat(Cantidad) * parseFloat(Precio)) - (parseFloat(Cantidad) * parseFloat(Precio)) * (parseFloat(Descuento) / 100));
            tdescuento += ((parseFloat(Cantidad) * parseFloat(Precio)) * (parseFloat(Descuento) / 100));
            timpuesto += (((parseFloat(Cantidad) * parseFloat(Precio)) - (parseFloat(Cantidad) * parseFloat(Precio)) * (parseFloat(Descuento) / 100)) * (parseFloat(Impuesto) / 100));
            total += (((parseFloat(Cantidad) * parseFloat(Precio)) - (parseFloat(Cantidad) * parseFloat(Precio)) * (parseFloat(Descuento) / 100)) + (((parseFloat(Cantidad) * parseFloat(Precio)) - (parseFloat(Cantidad) * parseFloat(Precio)) * (parseFloat(Descuento) / 100)) * (parseFloat(Impuesto) / 100)));

            document.getElementById("subtotal").value = parseFloat(subtotal).toLocaleString("en");
            document.getElementById("tdescuento").value = parseFloat(tdescuento).toLocaleString("en");
            document.getElementById("timpuesto").value = parseFloat(timpuesto).toLocaleString("en");
            document.getElementById("total").value = parseFloat(total).toLocaleString("en");

            document.getElementById("cantidad").value = "1";
            document.getElementById("precio").value = "0";
            document.getElementById("buscarproducto").value = "";
            document.getElementById("idproducto").value = "";
            document.getElementById("existencia").value = "0";
            document.getElementById("impuesto").value = "0";
        }
</script>
```

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2, col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                <input value="Agregar Producto" id="btnShowModal" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>

            <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="productoModal"
                 data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar Producto</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                ×
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-6, col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                            <label for="buscarproducto">Producto </label>
                                            <input type="text" id="buscarproducto" name="buscarproducto" class="form-control" style="width: 100%" />
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-2, col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                                            <label>Cantidad</label>
                                            <input class=" form-control" type="text" value="1" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" />
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-2, col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                                            <label>Precio</label>
                                            <input class=" form-control" type="text" value="0" id="precio" name="precio" />
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-2, col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                                            <label>Existencia</label>
                                            <input class=" form-control" type="text" value="0" id="existencia" name="existencia" disabled="true" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <br />

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-4, col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                            <label>Unidad</label>
                                            @Html.DropDownList("Unidad", listaUnidad, null, new { @class = "form-control ", style = "width: 100%;max-width: 100%;" })
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-2, col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                                            <label>Descuento</label>
                                            <input class=" form-control" type="text" value="0" id="descuento" name="descuento" />
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-2, col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                                            <input class=" form-control" type="text" value="0" id="impuesto" name="impuesto" hidden />
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-2, col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                                            <input class=" form-control" type="text" value="true" id="idproducto" name="idproducto" hidden />
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-2, col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                                            <input class=" form-control" type="text" value="" id="unidad" name="unidad" hidden />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input value="Agregar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AgregaConcepto(); return false;" />
                            <button type="button" id="btnHideModal" class="btn btn-primary button button4">
                                Cancelar
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4, col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="font-weight:bold">
                        <label>Subtotal</label>
                        <input class=" form-control" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 20px" type="text" value="0.00" id="subtotal" name="subtotal" disabled="true" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-4, col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="font-weight:bold">
                        <label>Descuento</label>
                        <input class=" form-control" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 20px" type="text" value="0.00" id="tdescuento" name="tdescuento" disabled="true" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-4, col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="font-weight:bold">
                        <label>Impuesto</label>
                        <input class=" form-control" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 20px" type="text" value="0.00" id="timpuesto" name="timpuesto" disabled="true" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4, col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="font-weight:bold">
                        <label>Total</label>
                        <input class=" form-control" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 20px" type="text" value="0.00" id="total" name="total" disabled="true" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div id="divConceptos">
            <div class="table-responsive-sm table-responsive-md table-responsive-lg">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table" style="width:100%;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Codigo</th>
                            <th>Descripcion</th>
                            <th>Unidad</th>
                            <th>Cantidad</th>
                            <th>Precio</th>
                            <th>Descuento</th>
                            <th>Impuesto</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary" />
                @Html.ActionLink("Volver", "Index", "Clientes", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: No creo que el error sea en los __html__ o __js__ creo que podría tratarse del __css__

Comment: Como seria el css?  deme un ejemplo

Comment: Prueba con : `.modal .ui-autocomplete{z-index: 1100}`

Comment: Acabo de probar con el css y no funciona, tienen otra solucion?

Comment: Este es la solucion que averigue:    <style>
        .ui-autocomplete {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2150000000 !important;
            cursor: default;
            border: 2px solid #ccc;
            padding: 5px 0;
            border-radius: 2px;
        }
    </style>